# CodeIgniter: I can't login

Tags: codeigniter, authentication

I'm trying to make a login script in CodeIgniter, but I only have a blank page.

I want it to say "username or password is wrong" and if the username and password is correct it should set session to true. I hope some one can help me.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

class Login extends Controller {

    function index()
    {

        if ($this->_submit_validate() === FALSE) {
            $this->index();
            return;
        }


    }

    private function _submit_validate()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username',
            'trim|required|');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password',
            'trim|required');

        return $this->form_validation->run();
    }


    function is_logged_in()
    {
        $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
        if(!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != true)
        {
            echo 'Du har ikke adgang til denne side';   
            die();      
            //$this->load->view('login_form');
        }       
    }

}
```

And here is my view file:

```
        <h3>Medlem login</h3><br>
        <?php
        echo form_open('login/');
        echo validation_errors('<p class="error">');
        echo form_input('username', 'Username');
        echo form_password('password', 'Password');
        echo "<br />";
        echo form_submit('submit', 'login');
        echo anchor('signup', 'Opret Account');
        echo form_close();
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is completely wrong and does not follow the RESTful pattern. For starters, your index function will cause your script to block:

```
   function index()
{

    if ($this->_submit_validate() === FALSE) {
        $this->index();
        return;
    }


}
```

Instead of calling the index function again on failure, you should load your view of the form. Then add an else clause in case validation succeeds. Like:

```
   function index()
{

    if ($this->_submit_validate() === FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('view_form');
    } else {
        $this->function_to_set_session();
    }
}
```

In the function_to_set_session(), you'd then do something along these lines:

```
function login(){
    // set session vars
    $this->session->set_flash('flash_message_to_show_after_reload'); // this is the message on succes
    redirect('path_to_redirect');
}
```

I figure you're just getting started with CodeIgniter? If so, I advise to follow a tutorial.

Comment: hm im new and i have follow some tutorials but all do it different :S,

Comment: but i want to do if the username or password is wrong it get a error "wrong username os password" so no loading a new view file

Comment: But to show anything on your screen you need to load a view! So in case of an error reload your form view and use the form_helper of CodeIgniter to show the errors. In case of success, set your session variables and redirect your user to the correct page. This is how your flow should work.